# No llvm opt command in Mavericks

Tags: macos, optimization, llvm, osx-mavericks

I installed Xcode 5.0.1 on Macosx 10.9 Mavericks and the command line tools (I can use gcc/clang on the command line for instance) but the command `opt` seems to have disappeared.
Was it replaced by something else ?

Comment: What is the version of clang ?

Answer (score 11):

Apple never shipped 'base' LLVM tools with its within XCode command line tools, only clang. You need to compile the desired revision / release of LLVM by yourself. You can download the pre-built binaries at http://llvm.org/releases/download.html as well.

Answer (score 8):

My strategy (on Mavericks) was to do `brew install llvm` then symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.4/bin/opt /usr/bin/opt
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.4/bin/llc /usr/bin/llc
```

Comment: On Sierra install at: `/usr/local/bin/` because of [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection)

Answer (score 6):

I got this to work on High Sierra by installing it via Homebrew.

```
brew install llvm
```

Once you're done with that, Homebrew will tell you something like this:

```
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include


If you need Python to find bindings for this keg-only formula, run:
  echo /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/llvm.pth
```

Go ahead and run:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

to stick that into your `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a solution for El Capitan and Sierra since now it shows the error

`ln: /usr/bin/opt: Operation not permitted`

It's really simple, just go to `~/.bash_source` (or the rc file of whatever shell you have) and write `alias opt='/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/<llvm_version>/bin/opt'`