# Cabal fails to build OpenGLRaw when installing library "ghc: could not execute: opt"

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal

I am trying to compile a Haskell program using Cabal which uses the library [gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss),
which requires [OpenGL](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL).

This fails when Cabal tries to build OpenGLRaw:

```
...
Starting     OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0 (lib)
Building     OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0 (lib)

Failed to build OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0.
Build log ( /Users/rohan/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/OpnGLRw-3.3.4.0-5b38767b.log):
Configuring library for OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0..
Preprocessing library for OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0..
Building library for OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0..
[  1 of 617] Compiling Graphics.GL.Groups ( src/Graphics/GL/Groups.hs,dist/build/Graphics/GL/Groups.o,dist/build/Graphics/GL/Group.dyn_o )
[  2 of 617] Compiling Graphics.GL.Types ( src/Graphics/GL/Types.hs,dist/build/Graphics/GL/Types.o,dist/build/Graphics/GL/Types.dyn_o )
...
[560 of 617] Compiling Graphics.GL.APPLE.FlushBufferRange (src/Graphics/GL/APPLE/FlushBufferRange.hs, dist/build/Graphics/GL/APPLE/FlushBufferRange.o, dist/build/Graphics/GL/APPLE/FlushBufferRange.dyn_o )
[561 of 617] Compiling Graphics.GL.APPLE.Fence ( src/Graphics/GL/APPLE/Fence.hs, dist/build/Graphics/GL/APPLE/Fence.o, dist/build/Graphics/GL/APPLE/Fence.dyn_o )
ghc: could not execute: opt
cabal: Failed to build OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.0 (which is required by exe:lsystems from lsystems-0.1.0.0). See the build log above for details.
```

After a bit of digging around SO it seems the issue is likely with the `opt` command from `llvm` (for example see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274057/no-llvm-opt-command-in-mavericks#20298098) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796874/cant-install-diagrams-arithmoi-on-mac)). However, I have `llvm` installed and its commands are on my path. The following line:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/12.0.1/bin:$PATH"
```

is in the `.zshrc` file and running the command `opt --version` works fine. I also tried adding these environment variables:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$(llvm-config --includedir):$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(llvm-config --libdir):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

as this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396919/converting-hs-to-llvm-ir-ll-error-ghc-could-not-execute-opt-on) suggested, but that didn't work either.

Other possibly relevant information:

- I am using macOS Big Sur 11.5, on an ARM Mac.
- `cabal`, `ghc`, and `llvm` are installed with Homebrew
- Using `cabal 3.4.0.0`, `ghc 8.10.7`, and `opt 12.0.1`
- This process can fail at different steps. For example the build above failed at [561 of 617] but when I tried it just now it failed at [540 of 617].

Comment: Hi @rohan-hitchcock, did you find something? We followed your exact same steps and got stuck too.

Comment: @BetaZiliani No, I still don't know of any solution.